How many oracles can satisfy a solution of Simons problem?
I know that the f/oracles in Simons algorithm is 2-1, and that $f(x)=f(y)\iff y=x\oplus s$.
My question is if we can have gave different oracles/functions, that has the same codomain/output for a given s. And if so how many such oracles can we have ? And is there a way to compute how many?

I'm not sure to understand your question, are you asking, for a given $f$ satisfying Simon's promise, how many unitaries $U_f$ are there such that $U_f|x,y\rangle=|x,y\oplus f(x)\rangle$?

No, i was wondering how many f's can we have that satisfies the condition in Simon algorithm, for a specific s,

Let $f:\{0, 1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^m$ satisfying Simon's promise for a given $s$. We want to count how such many $f$ are there.
Let us assume $s\neq 0$ for now. Let $S_0$ be a subset of $\{0, 1\}^n$ such that $\left|S_0\right|=2^{n-1}$ and such that for all $x,y\in S_0$, $x\neq y\oplus s$. Basically, if we know $f$ on $S_0$, we completely know $f$ on $\{0, 1\}^n$. Let us denote $x_1,\cdot,x_{2^{n-1}}$ the elements of $S_0$.

We first choose $f\left(x_1\right)$, for which we have $2^m$ choices.
We then choose $f\left(x_2\right)$, for which we have $2^m-1$ choices.
...
We then choose $f\left(x_{2^{n-1}}\right)$, for which we have $2^m-2^{n-1}+1$ choices.

All in all, this results in $\prod\limits_{i=0}^{2^n-1}\left(2^m-i\right)=\frac{2^m!}{\left(2^m-2^{n-1}\right)!}$ functions.
If $s=0$, a similar reasoning yields $\frac{2^m!}{\left(2^m-2^n\right)!}$ functions.

Thank you, just to dobbel check. The reason $|S_{0}|=2^{n-1}$ is because f is 2 to 1, so we only map to half of the possible states?

And is probably should be $x\neq y\oplus s$ and $s\neq y\oplus s$

@PinkElephants Yes, once you hav chosen $f(0)$ for instance, the value of $f(s)$ is forced. So, once you have chosen a value for half the possible inputs, the rest of them is forced. Nice catch for your second comment!
